# Experiencing periodic mouse/keyboard lockups when booting to Windows 8 installation USB, then BSOD

Tags: windows-8, usb, installation, mouse, peripherals

I'm trying to upgrade my new build from Windows 7 64 bit to Windows 8 64 bit. When I boot to the USB the mouse and keyboard cut out every 2-3 seconds for about 2 seconds. Then when I hit the install now button, I get a BSOD.

[Here's some details of my build.](http://speccy.piriform.com/results/SIw7vXgc5FhtxFkGx56GYLF)

Comment: You are using the upgrade assistant correct?

Comment: I used an ISO and created a bootable USB, not using the update assistant.